# How to enable DFSR between Windows Server 2008 servers that aren't part of a domain?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, iis-7, dfs, dfs-r

I'm configuring two server as IIS web servers on Windows Server 2008 in load balancing mode. I want to enable DFS replication for synchronizing web content files and IIS configuration data (via IIS 7 shared configuration.)

The servers are not in a Windows domain. After I addded the DFS role, I'm getting the following error message in the event log:

> The DFS Replication service failed to
>   contact domain controller  to access
>   configuration information. Replication
>   is stopped. The service will try again
>   during the next configuration polling
>   cycle, which will occur in 60 minutes.
>   This event can be caused by TCP/IP
>   connectivity, firewall, Active
>   Directory Domain Services, or DNS
>   issues.
>
> Additional Information: 
>   Error: 1355 (The specified domain
>   either does not exist or could not be
>   contacted.)

I know [there are advantages having pure web servers in a domain](https://serverfault.com/questions/16773/should-windows-web-servers-be-members-of-an-active-directory-domain), but I want to know if this is a conditio-sine-qua-non or is there a way to configure DFRS between Windows Server 2008 servers without a Windows domain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Can I use DFS Replication in a workgroup?**

No. DFS Replication relies on Active Directory® Domain Services for configuration. It will only work in a domain.

[link here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773238(WS.10).aspx#BKMK_001)

Comment: Okay, I'm glad Microsoft decided for me. I'll create a domain :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why not set up a cluster for this purpose?  DFS Replication is not the way to go for this.

Comment: Why not? I read about DFS-R in a book about IIS 7 and it seems to be a valid method for synchronizing IIS meta data and web files. Which type of cluster do you mean?

Comment: I think you're going to have to be a member of a domain in order to use DFS, as the DFS root info is stored there.  Also, I was referring to VCS (veritas cluster service) as it has the ability to do active/active clustering.  I do not believe MSCS (microsoft clustering) can do active/active.  You may also want to take a look at the schedule for DFS-R, I know back in the 2003 days is was around 1 hour, which was unacceptable to us.  If that works for you, then you may want to use it.

Comment: I also did not like the fact that the macs in our environment were not compatible with DFS shares.